# SilverStripe CropperField options

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using SilverStripe Cropperfield: https://github.com/willmorgan/silverstripe-cropperfield

There should be a way to set the `aspect_ratio` option to set the cropperbox to a certain size. The documentation however is not entirely clear on where to put this option.

**Where can you set the options?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 4th option of the constructor, when you instantiate the field.

https://github.com/willmorgan/silverstripe-cropperfield/blob/master/code/CropperField.php#L89

Hope the module helps you!

Answer (score 3):

In the code...

https://github.com/willmorgan/silverstripe-cropperfield/blob/master/code/CropperField.php#L244

...this option is traced back to this static array...

https://github.com/willmorgan/silverstripe-cropperfield/blob/master/code/CropperField.php#L32

...which you can set at the time of construction - but that isn't what you are asking.  In silverstripe any static array can be set in the code, so for you I'd advise adding this to _confip.php

```
Config::inst()->update('CropperField', 'default_options',array(
        'aspect_ratio' => <SET ME HERE>,
        'crop_min_width' => 256,
        'crop_min_height' => 256,
        'crop_max_width' => null,
        'crop_max_height' => null,
        'generated_max_width' => 512,
        'generated_max_height' => 512,
));
```

making sure to set the required aspect ratio

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Though it was my intention to set the `option` at time of construction. If I set the `aspect_ratio` in the config as you have displayed, it will apply to *all* CropperField instances right? Whereas I would want to apply the option to a single instance only